# Too specific of namespacing/packaging

Tags: design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I'm about to start building a C# library for English and French morphology as a side project. The library will be later merged with other linguistic aspects (phonology, sentence parsing, etc). for other languages (Japanese and Russian).

Unfortunately, I have come across an issue in my design: my namespace hierarchy is a little crazy (in my opinion).

Here's the namespace for English sentence parsing (lexing stage):

`Linguistics.English.Syntax.Parsing.Lex`

The above namespace would include the necessary classes for using an existing English lexicon to parse a particular text.

The Japanese equivalent would be:

`Linguistics.Japanese.Syntax.Parsing.Lex`

They would be separate because the lexing process for each language is different. A more extreme example of the indicative present for French verb conjugations (inflections) would be:

`Linguistics.French.Inflection.Verb.Indicative.Present`

I know that I can just do `using Linguistics.French.Inflection.Verb` if I'm working on generating verb conjugation tables, but is the organization *too specific*?

More specifically, ***if/when* do namespaces become too-specific**? Am I being silly or is my concern actually a potential problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is opinion-based and open-ended, so I'm not offering anything undoubtedly acceptable, but

1. certainly, **good naming is hard** ← emphasis.

   I've found many times that coming up with good names or good system of names if they can't be easily changed with the use of refactoring tools later on, once the pilot was delivered out to the wild, is more difficult then just writing code in between the coding convention hinted margins.

   For instance renaming database tables and database fields while preserving the data and not breaking any stored procedures with dynamic queries is very tough technical task, best to be avoided. So good naming since the beginning can be very important sometimes.
2. That's why my advice is: before fixing down a namespacing rules, **draw some inspiration from** the name finding work already done by other developers developing **linguistic libraries** in programming languages supporting namespaces like `Python`, `Java`, `C#`...

   Some lists of linguistic libraries:

   - [Stack Overflow: Pluralize - Singularize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475705/pluralize-singularize)
   - [Stack Overflow: Java or Python for Natural Language Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904025/java-or-python-for-natural-language-processing)

   From the above lists, `NLTK (Python)` and `Stanford NLP (Java)` look like libraries that should not be underestimated.
3. From the software design perspective, if you **hide** the language-specific implementation details **behind interfaces** and behind a [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C.23), then the language-specific libraries can use whatever internal naming convention they like, without exposing the names to the outside and without the risk of breaking anything.

   That's what [System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService.CreateService Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.createservice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does

Comment: I suppose that I should have looked at how others have done it first! My original thought was  *someone is going to think this deep of a hierarchy is ridiculous* - I didn't thing that it was an opinion-based issue, but rather a practical one, so sorry for that. I have had to deal with renaming database tables and columns before, so I was trying to gauge what would be appropriate for namespaces *before* writing all of the code. Thank you for the sources!

Comment: @ChrisCirefice no need to sorry, your original thought is **good point**, thinking before writing is very **good point**, yes it is a **practical** problem, but answering the "_when namespaces become too-specific_" with well balanced list of best practices and quotations from books or rules of thumb is very **difficult** as it assumes someone with PhD level of worldwide knowledge, which I'm not. I have learned to study what other (smarter or more hardworking or more team-packed) guys did before doing my small steps very soon. That's why I recommend it (I'm older). **Good luck**

Answer (score 2):

Having the language (eg, English, French, Japanese) so far up in your namespace is a smell.  If I were you I'd keep the Language identifiers in the class names only.

The recommended structure for a namespace is something like

```
<company>.<project>.<namespace>.<subNamespace>.<andSoOn>
```

So, in your case, you might consider something like:

```
CC.Linguistics.Syntax.Parsing.Lex
```

In which you would have the classes `EnglishLexicon`, `ItalianLexicon`, etc.

Comment: My original thought about the languages is this: each language is linguistically **very** different. For example, English morphology is completely different from Japanese morphology, the same goes for syntax, phonology, etc. They may all be languages, but the way they do each linguistic process is very different. Furthermore, I want each language to be completely separable; if I want to work on something to do with morphology in English, I don't want to do `using  Linguistics.Morphology` and clutter my project with classes for French, Japanese, etc. when I know that I won't be using those.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Are you sure languages are really totally different so you absolutely CANNOT find any similarities? For example, [German languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_languages), though different, have many common sides. Writting EVERYTHING for each new language literally from scratch is not appropriate.

Comment: Remember that namespaces are for organizing Domain Model concepts, not necessarily Domain concepts *per se*.

Comment: @FractalizeR There may be *some* similarities, sure. For example, one could make the assumption that the majority of languages have a grammar (if not all of them!). However, the *implementation* of each language varies dramatically. In order to separate them as much as possible, I put language as a higher entity in the hierarchy, because less is shared between them than is different. Moreover, the question was about whether something like `Linguistics.French.Inflection.Verb.Indicative.Present` was *too specific* and if it could be done differently/more effectively.

Comment: @FractalizeR Example: in trying to model French lexical entries I would need masculine/feminine/neutral marker whereas in English I would not. Same goes for conjugations. Japanese does not have a true future tense while English and French do. So how could one go about building common structures when they differ so largely? Some languages don't even have a phonology (sign languages)! It would involve keeping track of a million tiny differences; my idea is that it **is** better to start from scratch for each language (thus its own namespace).

Comment: @ChrisCirefice I am not a linguist. But about your gender example, I could say, that there are thousands of languages having notion of gender. Many languages have three gender categories. masculine/feminine/neutral division is true at least for Russian, German, Spanish ... and even in English there is a notion of three gender types, though not so vividly showed in a grammar (for example, when people speak about ships, they tend to use feminine gender). Anyway, I am not a linguist ;)

Comment: @ChrisCirefice [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender#By_language) says, that most languages has two or three genders. And their properties seem pretty common to me ;)

Comment: @FractalizeR True, maybe a lot of them do :) I plan on working on these languages separately as I learn them, so I was trying to get a good organizational structure that would allow me to separate them as such... I can't currently make design decisions about 'what's shared' because I don't know, for the moment :)

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Well, then you should make a good guess ;)